# Can't open jupyter lab from terminal

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab

`$ jupyter lab`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lirt/miniconda3/bin/jupyter-lab", line 5, in <module>
    from jupyterlab.labapp import main
  File "/Users/lirt/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jupyterlab/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .handlers.announcements import (
  File "/Users/lirt/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jupyterlab/handlers/announcements.py", line 14, in <module>
    from jupyter_server.base.handlers import APIHandler
  File "/Users/lirt/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jupyter_server/base/handlers.py", line 23, in <module>
    from jupyter_events import EventLogger
  File "/Users/lirt/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jupyter_events/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .logger import EVENTS_METADATA_VERSION, EventLogger
  File "/Users/lirt/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jupyter_events/logger.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .schema import SchemaType
  File "/Users/lirt/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jupyter_events/schema.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .validators import draft7_format_checker, validate_schema
  File "/Users/lirt/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jupyter_events/validators.py", line 41, in <module>
    JUPYTER_EVENTS_SCHEMA_VALIDATOR = Draft7Validator(  # type: ignore
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: create.<locals>.Validator.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'registry'
```

I can't open jupyter lab using bash commend while I can open it from Anaconda navigator. I don't know what's the problem here and it's annoying. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

please update your jupyter

```bash
pip install jupyter notebook -U
```